# How is prior.count used by edgeR's cpm

Tags: r, edger

edgeR's cpm function has an argument called `prior.count`. Based on my understanding of the documentation, it is supposed to be adding a fixed number per sample which is proportional to the library size of said sample. Average of all numbers added to all samples would be equal to `prior.count`.

However, looking at actual data this does not seem to be the case. Given an imaginary data frame of

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,0),c = c(1,2,3,0)*3, b = c(1,2,3,0)*2)
```

We can try to calculate log cpms by doing

```
logCPM = cpm(df,log = TRUE,prior.count = .5)
```

We can also calculate regular cpms by doing

```
CPM = cpm(df)
```

If we wanted to see, what is the number that is added to the CPMs before getting logged, we could do

```
difference = 2^logCPM - CPM
```

To make it look pretty lets use tibble

```
tibble::as.tibble(difference)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
                     a                    c                    b
                 <dbl>                <dbl>                <dbl>
1  25641                25641                25641              
2  12821                12821                12821              
3 -    0.0000000000582 -    0.0000000000582 -    0.0000000000582
4  38462                38462                38462
```

Here we see that the number that is added has no relation to the library size of the sample. What I want to learn is, how is this number that is added to each cpm is calculated based on prior.count.

I have been digging through the code but that part goes into C++ territory which hinders my understanding of what is going on

Comment: I get different results in the `difference` table. Which version are you using ? (I am in R 3.5.1 and edgeR 3.22.2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prior count ends up getting scaled by the ratio of a library size to the average library size and then multiplied by 2 before getting added to each library size (I'm sure there's a good reason for that, but I don't know what it is). Using the example `df` data frame in your post, let's walk step-by-step through what `cpm()` is doing:

```r
df = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,0),c = c(1,2,3,0)*3, b = c(1,2,3,0)*2)
prior.count = 0.5
# First, we need to calculate a library size
lib.size = colSums(df)
# Calculate the average library size and the adjusted priors
ave.lib = mean(lib.size)
adjusted.prior = prior.count * lib.size / ave.lib
# Update the library sizes
adjusted.lib.size = lib.size + 2*adjusted.prior
# Now we can compute the CPM
customCPM = t((log(t(df) + adjusted.prior) - log(adjusted.lib.size) + log(1000000))/log(2))
```

The matrix transposition looks really ugly in the last step, but it's needed so R adds things like `adjusted.prior` to each row of `df`.

Note that the prior count is only used if you compute log(CPM), it's unused otherwise.

Comment: How do you know that edgeR is scaling that way to obtain the adjusted.prior?  By the way `sweep`  could be used to avoid having to transpose the matrix

Comment: It's stated in the source code. I know I can use `sweep()`, but `t()` takes fewer characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way was I wrong about the code being within the C++ part? If that R code above was part of the package, I have missed it

Comment: You didn't miss it, I translated the C++ code to more accessible R. The C++ code is pretty tough to follow unless you're pretty comfortable with it.

Comment: thanks this is an awesome answer and helps me understand prior.count